# Is there any way setting font size in Reportlab?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to make simple chart using reportlab with python.

I made chart with title of x and y, but the font seems like small.

I wanna change font to be bold and increase font size.

here is my code.

```
def DrawPowerChart(self):

    arrX = [0]*6
    arrY = [0]*3
    for i in range(6):
        arrX[i] = i * 60
    for i in range(3):
        arrY[i] = i * 40    

    drawing = Drawing(400,400)

    self.data = [
        ((10,30), (40,3), (70,72), (100,33), (130,14), (160,52), (190,68), (220,37),(250,70),(280,80))
    ]

    lp = LinePlot()
    lp.x = 50
    lp.y = 50
    lp.height = 300
    lp.width = 300
    lp.data = self.data
    lp.joinedLines = 3
    lp.lines[0].strokeWidth = 4
    lp.strokeColor = colors.black
    lp.xValueAxis.valueMin = 0
    lp.xValueAxis.valueMax = 300
    lp.yValueAxis.valueMin = 0
    lp.yValueAxis.valueMax = 80
    lp.xValueAxis.valueSteps = arrX
    lp.yValueAxis.valueSteps = arrY
    drawing.add(String(360,40,"Time(s)")) #this is label x
    drawing.add(String(30,370,"Power(W)")) #this is label y
```

I knew if i use canvas i will be solved but I wanna make chart picture including title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See page 95 of the [ReportLab User Guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) for details. Here's an example of how you can change the font size *and* colour:

```
d.add(String(150,100, 'Hello World', fontSize=18, fillColor=colors.red))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be page 118?

Comment: It was rather dumb of me to cite a page reference in a URL whose content is liable to change. If I quoted the wrong number then thanks fo rthe correction.